# Can't remove Centos 7 kernel while updating to Centos 8

Tags: centos, upgrade

I am attempting to upgrade my Centos 7 installation to Centos 8 by following [this guide](https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-centos-7-to-centos-8/).

When I get to the step to remove the old kernel and run

```
rpm -e `rpm -q kernel`
```

I am met with several dozen errors concerning kmod-kvdo, here are a few:

```
kernel(vsnprintf) = 0x99195078 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64

kernel(wait_for_completion) = 0x6d0aba34 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64

kernel(wait_for_completion_interruptible) = 0x015ddbdc is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64

kernel(wake_up_process) = 0xe65cdceb is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
```

What do I do?

Comment: I think that guide simply isn't good. You don't have to remove that kernel.

Comment: also, you don't seem to need any of the EPEL stuff...

Comment: The approach shown in https://github.com/johnj/centos-to8-upgrade/blob/master/to8.sh seems way more sensible.

Comment: by the way, **very** urgent recommendation to have a backup of your data (mainly / nearly exclusively: your home directory) when doing any system upgrade. If that works cleanly, worst case a from-scratch installation of CentOS 8 isn't even that painful.

Comment: I would highly recommend against updating from one major release to another in order to avoid issues like this. Instead, backup your data and perform a fresh install of CentOS 8.